# Links behind jQuery UI Dialog are clickable on Android

Tags: android, jquery, html, jquery-ui, dialog

I'm using jQuery UI Dialog to display the contents of an external html file.

It works great on all browsers and devices except Android, where the links on the page behind the dialog window are clickable - i.e. if I tap somewhere inside the dialog window and there's a link underneath. They don't actually link through to anywhere but a big green boxes appears around the link.

How can I stop this happening?

```
$('#myBtn').click(function(e){
    var width = $(window).width() * 0.8;
    $('#dialog').html('');
    $('#dialog').load('retail.html').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        title: 'Browse By Genre',
        width: width,
        height: 'auto',
        position: ['top',20],
        modal: true
    $('#dialog').dialog('open');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually hide the page when I popup the dialog.  I have been having a lot issues with android and the dialog.  I am also getting off center clicks on finger input.